# How to make indexing in Couch Database?

Tags: couchdb, elasticsearch

In the elastic search i want to do indexing on multiple couch-databases for searching of record,is it Possible to index those databases at a time in couch database?????

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you want. You have X-times a couch database and want to index the data into ElasticSearch? Why not just use the couch db river plugin or implement indexing by yourself?

http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/2010/09/28/the_river_searchable_couchdb.html

Also there is

https://github.com/refuge/couch_es

Or you have ElasticSearch and want to feed couch?